# How to manage URL with or without ? and /

Tags: regex, seo, koa, koa-router

In my Koa app, I've this kind of router :

```
app
    .use(router(app))
    .all('/', frontRoutes.home.index);
```

My problem is that :

- mydomain.com
- mydomain.com/
- mydomain.com?

Are routed by the same route. It could be great but for Google it's not. Says that it's duplicate content. So I would like to redirect the first and third to the second. Like something to this :

```
app
    .use(router(app))
    .redirect('/\?', '/', 301)
    .redirect('', '/', 301)
    .all('/', frontRoutes.home.index);
```

Have tried some regexp without success. Already opened a Github issue but without answer too : https://github.com/alexmingoia/koa-router/issues/251 .

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: It seems that [`path-to-regexp`](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp) anchors the value you pass as a pattern by default. Try `'\??'` expression. Something like `.redirect('\??', '/', 301)`.

Comment: Don't seems to solve the bug... Have tried, doesn't work :( Thansk for your try of helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no issue with koa-router. You can accomplish this with plain old middleware:

```
// Redirects "/hello/world/" to "/hello/world"
function removeTrailingSlash () {
  return function * (next) {
    if (this.path.length > 1 && this.path.endsWith('/')) {
      this.redirect(this.path.slice(0, this.path.length - 1))
      return
    }
    yield * next
  }
}

// Redirects "/hello/world?" to "/hello/world"
function removeQMark () {
  return function * (next) {
    if (this.path.search === '?') {
      this.redirect(this.path)
      return
    }
    yield * next
  }
}

// Middleware

app.use(removeTrailingSlash())
app.use(removeQMark())
app.use(router(app))

// Routes

app
  .all('/', frontRoutes.home.index)

app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: There is a little bug, I had to replace `this.path` by `this.originalUrl`. But all the rest works, thanks again !